# clojure-jack-in error

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime

I installed clojure-mode and slime using the emacs starter kit and I get this error when I do clojure-jack-in -

```
Symbols value as variable is void: slime-clj
```

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was installing the wrong emacs plugin. 'slime-clj' instead of 'slime-ritz'.

Comment: actually, the emacs plugin was the problem, not project.clj